# How can I play a sound on mouseenter event, without clicking on the document first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, mouseenter

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="word">word</div>

<audio id="player">
    <source id="source" src"sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

and the following JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$('#word').mouseenter(function()
{
    var audio = $("#player")[0];
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
});
```

On my browser this code only works, if I **click** on the document first. Otherwise it does not work and in the JavaScript console I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play method is not allowed by
> the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly
> because the user denied permission.

and this warning:

> Automatic playback is permitted only when accepted by the user, the
> user has interacted with the site or the media file has the volume set
> to zero.

If I set the volume to zero, I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The fetching process for the media
> resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request.

I tried both on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: The warning is your answer.

Comment: No, it is not possible. And please stop trying to make my life difficult by playing sounds every time I mouse over things. Let me decide whether I want sounds to play.

Comment: @Teemu That is?

Comment: @HereticMonkey On duolingo (https://www.duolingo.com/learn) it is implemented like that somehow. Actually, if you refresh the page, it doesn't work, but the first time the page is loaded, it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="word" style="font-size: 30px; margin-bottom: 200px; ">word</div>
    
<audio id="player" controls preload="auto">
     <source src="audio/beep.mp3" controls></source>
     <source src="audio/beep.ogg" controls></source> 
</audio>
 
<script>
    var player = $("#player")[0];
        $("#word").mouseenter(function() {              
        player.play();
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but on my browser it does not work.

Comment: An answer with just code is rarely helpful, especially when it is much the same as the OPs. See [answer] for more.

Comment: which browser you are using, as you need to add entire code in body section and add jquery library file (compressed one). Like this Add this link in head section  

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).